# How i can work wordpress plugin shortcode every 10 second without page refresh?

Tags: php, wordpress, page-refresh

I use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[venue id="3fd66200f964a520d6f01ee3"]'); ?>` shortcode on my wp. But I want to work this shortcode every 10 second without page refresh. How can I do it?

Comment: Use jQuery ajax to send request to php page and your php page will have extract the shortcode php code and return the output in your desired container or div, for every 10 second use setInterval function to 10 seconds and call jquery ajax function.

Comment: @Noman Can you write your code?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for solving the problem, you ll have to write your code.

Comment: @Noman You are right but I don't know to  use ajax? My problem is this.

Comment: Searching is your best friend. you have to search for `jquery ajax with wordpress shortcodes`